# how to logrotate(8) tell the process that inode has changed?

Tags: linux, logrotate

say biz.log:

I read the logrotate(8) defaults to (1) rename the old log file with the date, biz.log.20220129 and then (2) create a new file with the origin name, and finally
(3) change the process's log output to the new file inode.

My question is the fact that the biz-process uses the inode instead of the file makes step1, and step2 reasonable. But how does the (3) work? I am not sure how logrotate can tell the process the log file should be reopened, and do I have to add some code to handle this in my project?

Answer (score 1):

It requires cooperation between logrotate and application. Logrotate must be configured through `postrotate scripts`, to emit signal (i.e. SIGUSR), which application must handle - by reopening log files by their name. Actually one may also use different interprocess communication method, but i believe signals are common. See for example discussion on logrotate for httpd configuration (https://serverfault.com/questions/262868/logrotate-configuration-for-httpd-centos).

If there is no option to modify application, to work with signals for file rotation, one may configure logrotate to use `copytruncate` option - where logrotate copy current file to backup file, and then truncates current file to 0 bytes. If file is opened by application in append mode, it should be seamless. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html `copytruncate` section.